# Testng running sequence of the test case is changed after updating to 6.14.2

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

Previously I am using testng 6.8.8 version and all tests are executed as expected. But before a few days back **I updated testng version to 6.14.2**, Started facing running sequences issue. I also tried with priority change and all things but it's not working as it was working in testng 6.8.8. Refer source code for more details.

**class1.java**

```
    package TestNG;

    import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    public class class1
    {
    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeclass1()
    {
        System.out.println("before_class1");

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterclass1()
    {
        System.out.println("after_class1");

    }

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void class1_method1()
    {
        System.out.println("class1_method1");
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void class1_method2()
    {
        System.out.println("class1_method2");

    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void class1_method3()
    {
        System.out.println("class1_method3");

    }
}
```

**class2.java**

```
package TestNG;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class class2
{

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeclass1()
    {
        System.out.println("before_class2");

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterclass1()
    {
        System.out.println("after_class2");

    }

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void class2_method1()
    {
        System.out.println("class2_method1");
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void class2_method2()
    {
        System.out.println("class2_method2");

    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void class2_method3()
    {
        System.out.println("class2_method3");

    }
}
```

**class3.java**

```
package TestNG;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class class3
{

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeclass1()
    {
        System.out.println("before_class3");

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterclass1()
    {
        System.out.println("after_class3");

    }

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void class3_method1()
    {
        System.out.println("class3_method1");
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void class3_method2()
    {
        System.out.println("class3_method2");

    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void class3_method3()
    {
        System.out.println("class3_method3");

    }
}
```

**testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test" >
    <classes>
      <class name="TestNG.class1">
        <methods>
          <include name="class1_method1"/>
          <include name="class1_method2"/>
          <include name="class1_method3"/>
          <include name="beforeclass1"></include>
          <include name="after_class1"></include>
          </methods>
      </class>
      <class name="TestNG.class2">
       <methods>
          <include name="class2_method1"/>
          <include name="class2_method2"/>
          <include name="class2_method3"/>
          <include name="beforeclass2"></include>
          <include name="after_class2"></include>         
          </methods>
      </class>
      <class name="TestNG.class3">
          <methods>
          <include name="class3_method1"/>
          <include name="class3_method2"/>
          <include name="class3_method3"/>
          <include name="beforeclass3"></include>
          <include name="after_class3"></include>
          </methods>
       </class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**Actual Output after running testng.xml using testng(6.14.2):**

> before_class1
>
> class1_method1
>
> before_class2
>
> class2_method1
>
> before_class3
>
> class3_method1
>
> class1_method2
>
> class2_method2
>
> class3_method2
>
> class1_method3
>
> after_class1
>
> class2_method3
>
> after_class2
>
> class3_method3
>
> after_class3

**Expected Output :(Working fine with testng 6.8.8 but not working in testng 6.14.2)**

> before_class1
>
> class1_method1
>
> class1_method2
>
> class1_method3
>
> after_class1
>
> before_class2
>
> class2_method1
>
> class2_method2
>
> class2_method3
>
> after_class2
>
> before_class3
>
> class3_method1
>
> class3_method2
>
> class3_method3
>
> after_class3

Comment: add <test name="Test"  preserve-order="true"> ,in your testng.xml file. Which set preserve-order="true".

Answer (score 0):

This setup will work till 6.9.10, after that priority is global for a test tag.

Use `dependsOnMethods or depednsOnGroups` to run in order first inside a class. You will need to use `alwaysRun = true` if you want to run the method if the method it depends on fails.

Also you can try just splitting the classes into different test tags.

Also not sure if there is a need to mention the before and after methods in the methods tag.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you explain this with one example or explain with files which I shared on this question

Comment: Refer to this. Pretty easy to do it -- http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods